# Format decimal c# - Keep last zero

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have been searching for this but cannot seem to find the answer. I have the following decimals with the corresponding output that I want from String.Format

100.00 -> 100
100.50 -> 100.50
100.51 -> 100.51

My problem is that I cannot seem to find a format which will keep the 0 on the end of 100.50 as well as remove the 2 zeros from 100.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**
For some more clarity. I have variables of type decimal, they are only ever going to be 2 decimal places. Basically I want to display 2 decimal places if they exist or none, I don't want to display one decimal place in the case of 100.50 becoming 100.5

Comment: You want "100.50"  to become "1.50" ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this:

```
string s = number.ToString("0.00");
if (s.EndsWith("00"))
{
    s = number.ToString("0");
}
```

Comment: As with tobias86's answer, this doesn't work on all machines, as some use a comma for the decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Sorry should have been more clear about culture, I can ignore it in this case. This works perfectly.

Comment: It might be marginally safer to replace `s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 3)` with `s = number.ToString("0")`, just in case there might be some weird culture that uses a multi-character decimal point. Granted, that does seem pretty unlikely, but just as a matter of principle it's always best to make as few assumptions as you can.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Since we're talking strange cultures and not relying on assumptions... if we assume a) that the inputs could be negative and b) that the [NumberNegativePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbernegativepattern.aspx) is 3, then my solution again doesn't work! Sigh... I guess sometimes it's simpler to just make some assumptions instead of trying to solve all the whole world's problems.

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know, there is no such format. You will have to implement this manually, e.g.:

```
String formatString = Math.Round(myNumber) == myNumber ? 
                      "0" :     // no decimal places
                      "0.00";   // two decimal places
```

Comment: @MarkusJarderot: Indeed. Only the OP can answer whether this is desired behaviour or not. He does not include an example with more digits.

Comment: The best solution so far. Thanks for this

Answer (score 5):

Test if your number is an integer, and use according format :

```
string.Format((number % 1) == 0 ? "{0}": "{0:0.00}", number)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this hurts my eyes, but should give you what you want:

```
string output = string.Format("{0:N2}", amount).Replace(".00", "");
```

**UPDATE:** I like Heinzi's answer more.

Comment: This doesn't work on my machine, where a comma is the default for the decimal. :)

Comment: @AndersHolmström True... I didn't think of localization.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will achieve the desired result while applying the specified culture:

```
decimal a = 100.05m;
decimal b = 100.50m;
decimal c = 100.00m;

CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");

string sa = String.Format(new CustomFormatter(ci), "{0}", a); // Will output 100,05
string sb = String.Format(new CustomFormatter(ci), "{0}", b); // Will output 100,50
string sc = String.Format(new CustomFormatter(ci), "{0}", c); // Will output 100
```

You can replace the culture with CultureInfo.CurrentCulture or any other culture to fit your needs.

The CustomFormatter class is:

```
public class CustomFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public CultureInfo Culture { get; private set; }

    public CustomFormatter()
        : this(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    { }

    public CustomFormatter(CultureInfo culture)            
    {
        this.Culture = culture;
    }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;

        return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (formatProvider.GetType() == this.GetType())
        {
            return string.Format(this.Culture, "{0:0.00}", arg).Replace(this.Culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + "00", "");
        }
        else
        {
            if (arg is IFormattable)
                return ((IFormattable)arg).ToString(format, this.Culture);
            else if (arg != null)
                return arg.ToString();
            else
                return String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```